# In Groovy - How to add comma in git tag list?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

I am doing git tag on a repo and getting below output.

**command**

```
def tagversion = sh(script:""" git tag --sort=v:refname """, returnStdout:true).trim()
```

**Output:-**

```
1.0
1.10.0
1.11.0
1.6
1.7
1.7.1
```

how can i add comma after each version?

**expected output**

```
1.0,
1.10.0,
1.11.0,
1.6,
1.7,
1.7.1
```

I have tried below code which works but add comma at last version as well and the entire list is showing as single string.

```
sh(script:""" git tag --sort=v:refname | tr '\n' ',' """, returnStdout:true).trim()
```

Comment: after your first line add this and see if thats the output you want?
`println tagversion.join(',\n')`

Comment: @Kaus2b- No, .join is not working.

Comment: Did the solution from @daggett work for you? I'm trying to use git tag --list '<filter>' but it seems to always only grab the last value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sh` returns you a string, `readLines()` will split it to an array, `join` will put it back to string with some delimiter

```
sh(...).trim().readLines().join(',\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are a fan of shell script:

```
stage('Test') {
        steps { script {
            def tagversion = sh(script:''' git tag --sort=v:refname | awk '{printf "%s%s",SEP,$0;SEP=", "}END{print ""}' | tr ' ' '\\n' ''', returnStdout:true).trim()
            echo tagversion
        }}
    }
```

taking from answer from @daggett which has a slight escape char mistake:

```
stage('Test') {
        steps { script {
            def tagversion = sh(script:''' git tag --sort=v:refname ''', returnStdout:true).trim().readLines().join(',\n')
            echo tagversion
        }}
    }
```